# How to automatically execute onclick?

Tags: click

I have code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="call(8969)" id="btn" class="zoombox"></a>
```

When I click button, this code will execute. Now, I want it is execute automatically when I visit website. How to do that ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Use on load:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onload event should suffice, otherwise, use JQuery.

```
<body onload="call(8986);" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery trigger event, you can do this:

```
window.onload = function(){
     $('#btn').trigger('click')   
 }
```